# What is the Objective-C equivalent of Double.NaN in Java?

Tags: java, objective-c, floating-point, nan, porting

What is the Objective-C equivalent of `Double.NaN` from Java? I've got a function that returns a double, but it has two cases where it can return `Double.NaN`. How would I implement that in Objective-C?

Comment: Does your function return a primitive `double` or an object `NSNumber`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
double nan = NAN;
```

Pretty simple. :)

Answer (score 11):

```
#include <math.h>

...
return NAN;
```

simple as that.  If for some reason you cannot include `<math.h>`, you can also use

```
return __builtin_nan("");
```

with either GCC or clang.

Incidentally, like most low-level language features of Objective-C, this is inherited directly from C.  The relevant portion of the C spec is §7.12:

> The macro `NAN` is defined if and only if the implementation supports quiet NaNs for the float type. It expands to a constant expression of type float representing a quiet NaN.

As you learn Objective-C, keep in mind that *every* C program is an Objective-C program, and there's nothing wrong with using C language features to solve your problem.